# insertAfter вставляет элемент перед родителем

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Структура HTML следующая:

```
<div class="comEnt" id="comEnt1" data-level="0">
    <span class="com_rating">4</span>
    Комментарий
</div>
<div class="comEnt" id="comEnt3" style="padding-left:20px" data-level="1" data-parent="comEnt1">
    <span class="com_rating">20</span>
</div>
<div class="comEnt" id="comEnt4" style="padding-left:20px" data-level="1" data-parent="comEnt1">
    <span class="com_rating">18</span>
</div>
<div class="comEnt" id="comEnt5" style="padding-left:40px" data-level="1" data-parent="comEnt4">
    <span class="com_rating">4</span>
</div>
<div class="comEnt" id="comEnt6" style="padding-left:60px" data-level="1" data-parent="comEnt5">
    <span class="com_rating">2</span>
</div>
<div class="comEnt" id="comEnt2" data-level="0">Комментарий</div>
```

Cначала идет сортировка `.comEnt` по значению в `.com_rating` (сортировка комментариев по рейтингу по убыванию):

```
$('.comEnt').sort(function (b, a) {
    return $(a).find('.com_rating').text() - $(b).find('.com_rating').text();
}).each(function (_, container) {
    $(container).parent().append(container);
});
```

У "родительского" комментария есть `id` (например, `comEnt5114276`).

У "ответного" комментария есть атрибут `data-parent` (например, `data-parent="comEnt5114276"`).

Затем идёт подстановка "ответных" комментариев под "родителя" 
(по структуре HTML `<div>`'ы между собой не связаны):

```
$('.comEnt').each(function(){
    var parent = $(this).attr('data-parent');
    $(this).insertAfter('#'+parent+'');
    return false;
});
```

Эта самая "подстановка" работает через раз.

**Пример**:

- родительский комментарий: http://clubtone.net/load/2-1-0-421559#comEnt5114145
- ответный: http://clubtone.net/load/2-1-0-421559#comEnt5114199

Ответный почему-то находится выше родительского.

В чем моя ошибка, что я делаю не так?

**+ Дополнение:**

По каким то причинам работает корректно (на странице с примером), только если вызвать функцию повторно.

Понимаю что код убогий, моджет подскажите как оформить данный код

```
function find_parent() {     
    $('.comEnt').each(function() {
        var parent = $(this).data('parent');
        $(this).insertAfter('#' + parent);
    });
}

setTimeout(find_parent, 0);
setTimeout(find_parent, 0);
```

более корректно?

Comment: В jQuery есть метод .after(). Попробуйте его. Ну и задержку сделайте. Не успевают выстроиться комментарии, видимо, раз впиливаются ответы раньше

Answer (score 1):

Вы не используете древовидную структуру HTML для древовидной структуры данных, что было бы и с точки зрения семантики и с технической - правильнее и проще.
В данном конкретном случае попробуйте использовать небольшую задержку после перемещения комментария, перед перемещением его ответов:

```
setTimeout(function () { moveAnswers() }, 1);
```